# How to split orders between sellers and buyers Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm building a platform where a user can sign up and add products to sell. Also another user can buy products listed. When a buyer place an order, i want it to be seen by a seller(user) who listed the product. Right now all users can see all orders even if they are not sellers.

I have no idea how to proceed but here is my

order function in product controller

```
 //Orders View Function
public function viewOrders(){
    $orders = Order::with('orders')->orderBy('id','Desc')->get();
    return view('orders')->with(compact('orders'));
 }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: it all depends on your database structure how you have designed it.
if you can show you db structure and what you have tried so far

Comment: In my database there are two tables `orders table` which has product_id, user_id, shipping_name,and shipping_city, also another table `order_product table` which has order_id, product_id, and  quantity. @Salman

Answer (score 0):

Your `viewOrders` action should be hidden behind authentication process (obviously, user has to first sign in before he can view his orders). Once you do that (using `auth` middleware for it's route), Laravel can resolve authenticated user for you - you can simply hint it as a parameter of your `viewOrders` action:

```
public function viewOrders(User $user)
{
    $orders = $user->orders()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

    return view('orders')->with(compact('orders'));
}
```

As you notice, here I've modified your query a little bit. Instead of selecting all orders we are now selecting them through authenticated user's *relation* to it's orders. Orders obviously belong to user, but through products (as an intermediate) - one user can have many products, one product can have many orders, thus one user can have many orders. In Laravel this kind of relationship between eloquent models is called [HasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through). Therefore you should declare it in your `User` model:

```
class User extends Model {
    ...

    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Order::class, Product::class);
    }
}
```

Note that your `Product` will probably also have `orders()` relation, but it will be of `HasMany` type instead since it's a direct one without any intermediates.

Comment: Now am getting this`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'orders.products_model_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `orders`.*, `products`.`user_id` as `laravel_throu` @d3jn

Comment: In my products model It is renamed as "Products_model" so I had to change `Product::class` to `Products_model::class`

Comment: @joh if your names differ from Laravel's naming convention then you will have to specify correct table and foreign key names for your relations. In your case it will be `$this->hasManyThrough(Order::class, Product_model::class, 'user_id', 'product_id');` (Laravel tries to guess your foreign key column names based of your model names, so for `Product_model` it was expecting `product_model_id` to exist).

Comment: It gives this `Call to a member function orderBy() on null` @d3jn

Comment: @joh `hasManyThrough()` can not under any circumstances return null value. It always returns instance of `HasManyThrough` relation object. So make sure you actually return it from your relation `orders()` function in `User` model.

Answer (score 0):

Filter your query base on your needs

Example:

**Model Relationship**

```
public function orders(){
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
}
```

```
public function getMyOrders(User $user){
    $orders = Order::with('orders')->orderBy('id','Desc')->where('user_id','=', $user->id)->get();
return view('orders')->with(compact('orders'));
}
```

To get sellers Orders

```
public function getSellerOrders(User $user){
    $products = Product::where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->get();
    $orders = [];
    foreach($products as $product){
        array_merge($orders, $product->order);
    }
    return view('orders')->with(compact('orders'));
}
```

Comment: I tried get SellersOrders but it show empty, no orders @Carl

Comment: can you check if you get value from the $products. try adding dd( $products) after the query

Comment: It shows this value `Collection {#276 ▼
  #items: []
}` @Carl

Answer (score 0):

In your DB table for `orders` you are suggested to have 2 IDs, one which denotes Buyer and Other which denotes Seller, i.e., Whenever a user places an order, then it must be a buyer then insert it's(buyer) ID into `buyer_id` in Order's table, similarly the `product_id` for denoting produc from Products' Table should be there and from Product's Table you can get `seller_id` which is suggested to be there for denoting which seller owns a particular product. Insert `seller_id` into Order's Table and use it to your query as:

```
$seller = Order::where('seller_id',$variable_for_product_id)->with('orders')->get();
```

Do this for all sellers in your Order's Table

Comment: what does this mean $variable_for_product_id @Sumit

Comment: @helloworld `$variable_for_product_id` is the variable which have the ID of seller from `orders` table i.e., `seller_id` as a foreign key from Seller's Table to Order's  Table, which is inserted with the help of `seller_id` in product's table